# Adjusting a merged column's width using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am creating a program which writes data into Excel cells. The problem is that Excel does not allow autofit on merged cells. Thus, I have to manually adjust width and height.

I have tried the following:

```
xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4]].ColumnWidth = 10;
```

and

```
xlWorksheet.Range[xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4], xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 4]].EntireColumn.Width = 10;
```

and all other codes I searched but all of those returns an error which says **Unable to set column width**

I don't have anything else left to do. Your help will be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly set a column width in this way

```
xlWorkSheet.Columns[3].ColumnWidth = 16;
```

for the worksheet, you need to loop through the columns that you need to set their width

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
xlWorkSheet.Columns[i].ColumnWidth = 16;
```